# Putting element next to fixed div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a div next to a fixed div, but what happens instead is the div is put inside the fixed div. How can I make it so that the div is placed next to the fixed div? I know I can use `float: right` with the div, but is there a way of doing it without using floats, with just `inline-block`? Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u81rp6Lo/1/).

**HTML**

```
  <div id='column'>

  </div>
  <div id='content'>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: -1;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your fixed element is `20%` wide, you can use `margin-left: 20%` to move `#content` to the right of it.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: -1;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
  <div id='column'>

  </div>
  <div id='content'>

  </div>
```